# Error when inserting vector of objects into set of vectors of objects

Tags: c++

I would like to populate a set with a vector of `tile` objects, but I get an error.

```cpp
#include <set>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct tile
{
    int value;
    int suit;
};

tile makeTile(const int &a, const int &b)
{
    tile t{a, b};
    return t;
}

int main()
{
    set<vector<tile>> s;
    vector<tile> v;
    v.push_back(makeTile(0, 0));
    s.insert(v); // Error
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Error message.]

I don't get an error if I use integers rather than objects.

```cpp
#include <set>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    set<vector<int>> s;
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(0);
    s.insert(v); // No error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please include the error as text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please build your code to get the build error message as text, [edit] your question and copy-paste the error text *as text* into the question. Also please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* output.

Comment: A hint about the problem though: The [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) container is *ordered*. To keep the order, the data inside the set needs to be comparable with less-than `<`. If there's no such operator for the data in the set you need to define such an operator. Or if ordering is not relevant, then perhaps use the unordered [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set)?

Answer (score 0):

you can't make a set(actually ordered) of objects where logical operation is not possible. 
But definitely you can make set by defining the logical operation by yourself. In programming sense, you can make set after doing some operator overloading.
Actually set is ordered set so you need to overload `<` operator for your struct.

Here is the code segment;

```cpp
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

struct tile{
     int value;
     int suit;

     bool operator<(const tile& a);
};

tile makeTile(const int &a, const int &b)
{
     tile t{a,b};
     return t;
}
bool operator<(const tile& a, const tile& b){
         return a.value <= b.value;
}

int main()
{
     set<vector<tile> > s;
     vector<tile> v;
     v.push_back(makeTile(0,0));
     v.push_back(makeTile(0,5));
     v.push_back(makeTile(-1,5));
     s.insert(v); // No Error here
}
```

if you want to check it then you can check it by following code:

```cpp
for(auto &i:s){
       for(auto &b:i){
           cout << b.value << " " << b.suit << endl;
       }
    }
```

hope it will help.